# MLCP import Exception

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

I have a csv file of size 1GB, I tried to import the csv file as a binary file using Marklogic mlcp-8.0.6,

```
./mlcp.sh import -mode local -options_file (portname, portno, username, password) -input_file_path "/input_path/file.csv" -document_type binary -output_uri_replace "input_path,'/output_path/'"
```

but it throwed an exception as mentioned below:

```
INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: BINARY
INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectorInputFormat: Total input paths to process: 1
INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: completed 0%
INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: completed 100%
ERROR contentpump.MulithreadedMapper: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

Could anyone mention why it happens? Is it due to the size of file. But when I tried to load the same file using `xdmp:document-load` function, it has been loaded into the document.

```
xdmp:document-load('input_path/file.csv',
  <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
    <uri>ouput_path</uri>
    <format>binary</format>
  </options>
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you loading as binary on purpose? More common for .csv is -document_type=xml or json and -input_file_type=delimited. See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_70366

Comment: yes i am loading data as binary for some data size testing purpose.